# I can't seem to make a payment out of my bank account. What can I do?

Tags: credit-card, ach, electronic-payment

I am an expat living overseas. But I still make several purchase using my US credit card (Citi Card).  Recently my electronic credit card payment (for my monthly bill) was returned with a code saying my bank account (Truist) is closed. I called Truist and was told that my account is active and there should be no problem with it paying bills. As Citi already removed my Truist account after the payment return, I tried re-linking it as a payment option. Citi then made small deposits to verify my account; deposits came in swiftly.

Yet, (after the account verification) when I tried again to pay for my credit card bill, it was rejected with the same code. It seems like I can make deposits, but not payment with this account. Who should I call in this case? The bank (Truist) or the credit card company (Citi). I think I should call my bank first. But then what if they keep saying there is nothing wrong with my account? Has anyone of you seen/experienced a similar case?

p.s.) If this question is not pertinent here, I am sorry, and I'd appreciate it if you could tell me where I could post this kind of question.

Comment: It's not clear what your situation is. Is it that Citi is the issuing bank for your credit card, and you have payments to Citi set up from your Truist bank account? Why are transactions with your credit card dependent on your Truist bank account?

Comment: Right. It could be more convenient if I also have a checking account with Citi. But I don't.

Comment: Does "_Recently my credit card payment (via internet) was returned_" mean something you tried to buy and pay for with your credit card, or a payment _to_ your CC (from your bank account) to clear previous spending on the CC?

Comment: Did you initiate the credit card bill payment on the bank's web site, or on the credit card's web site? If both of these transfer/payment options are available, did you try each?

Comment: @TripleHpund Oh, it's for my monthly credit card payment. So it's to clear previous spending. I will also edit that sentence to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Comment: @Chris W. Rea I did it on the credit card's website.

Comment: So Citi is trying to make an ACH debit at Truist, and failing, for the full amount, but can make it for a trivial amount?

Comment: Is there an option to pay bills from your bank's web site? Did you try that?

Comment: @Joe Yes, for some weird reason.